# How to use Numpy in VScode?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I have VScode and `python 3.10.11` installed on my computer and i have installed `numpy` as well using the `pip` command in cmd. But i still cannot access `numpy` in vs code.

I used the `pip install numpy` command in cmd and the library was installed. i can run it in the python's ide but not in VScode.
Update:
the above issue is solved but now the code shows no output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeFJF.png)

Comment: you have multiple python interpreters installed, and you've installed numpy into your a Python 3.8 interpreter

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`  to open the Command Palette.
Type Reload Window and select the ( Developer: Reload Window ) command from the list that appears. This will refresh the VSCode window and the library should appear as normally installed

Comment: read the VSC Python doc for **virtual environment**, create one for the correct Python version and install numpy in this virt env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install the *numpy* package in **python38**, but you use **python 3.10.11** in vscode. There are two solutions:

- Install *numpy* for **python 3.10.11**

  ```
  full/path/to/python3.10.11/python.exe -m pip install numpy
  ```
- Use **python38** in vscode

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` --> **python38**

Answer (score 0):

Please install the numpy package in VS console itself to solve this problem

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have correctly set up the virtual environment and chosen the interpreter where numpy is installed.

Comment: if you have installed numpy in **the interpreter** there is no need to have a virt env

Comment: I have made it clear that you installed numpy for the Python interpreter located at `C:\users\parneet kaur\appdata\local\programs\python \python38\python.exe`. However, you have configured Python 3.10.11 in VSCode.